# Dynamic programming spoj proof LISA

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve https://www.spoj.com/problems/LISA/

In the problem, the expression is given which has only *  and +. Placing bracket maximum value need to output.

like

```
 1+2*3+4*5 = (1+2)*(3+4)*5 = 105

 2*0*3+7+1*0*3 = 2*((0*3+7+1*0)*3) = 42
```

The implementation of 2D dynamic problem way of solving I came across is like below. Taking each number is matrix row and column and doing bottom to top approach.

```
f(ci,cj) = Max( f(i,j-1) operator c(i,j) , f( i+1,j-1) operator c(i,i) )

Like 3,5 =  Max of [  (3,4) * (5,5) or (3,3)+(4,5) ]
         =  Max of [   7*5  or 3+20 ] 
         =  Max of [ 35,23 ] = 35
```

I am not able to prove that the result I am getting is maximum and correct. How to prove below solution is max and optimal?

```
-----------------------------------
      C1   C2   C3   C4    C5
C1     1    3    9   13    105
C2          2    6   14    70
C3               3   7     35
C4                   4     20
C5                         5
```

Comment: To me, this equation : `f(ci,cj) = Max( f(i,j-1) operator c(i,j) , f( i+1,j-1) operator c(i,i) )` seems to be a little off. I think it needs to be `f(i,j) = Max( f(i,j-1) operator c(j,j) , c(i,i) operator f( i+1,j) )`. But then how would you fill `f(i,j)` without first getting `f(i+1, j)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my implementation: (it assumes the query is well-formed)

```
class LISASolver:
    def solve(self, query):
        """
        takes a query, a string with numbers and +, *,
        returns a tuple of min, max
        """
        numbers, operators = self.parse_inputs(query)
        n = len(numbers)
        self.numbers = numbers
        self.operators = operators
        self.memo = {}
        out = self.dp(0, len(numbers) - 1)
        return out

    def dp(self, i, j):
        if i == j:
            n = self.numbers[i]
            return n, n

        if (i, j) in self.memo:
            return self.memo[(i, j)]

        curmins = []
        curmaxs = []
        for k in range(i, j):
            o = lambda a, b: (a * b) if self.operators[k] == '*' else (a + b)
            leftmin, leftmax = self.dp(i, k)
            rightmin, rightmax = self.dp(k + 1, j)
            curmins.append(o(leftmin, rightmin))
            curmaxs.append(o(leftmax, rightmax))
        self.memo[(i, j)] = (min(curmins), max(curmaxs))

        return self.memo[(i, j)]

    def parse_inputs(self, query):
        numbers = []
        operators = []
        current_number = []

        for c in query:
            if c.isdigit():
                current_number.append(c)
            else:
                numbers.append(
                    int(''.join(current_number))
                )
                current_number = []
                operators.append(c)

        numbers.append(
            int(''.join(current_number))
        )
        return numbers, operators

s = LISASolver()
query = '1+2*3+4*5'
print(s.solve(query))
>>> 27, 105
query = '2*0*3+7+1*0*3'
print(s.solve(query))
>>> 0, 42
```

The subproblem is the optimal min and min result of the result from the i-th number to the j-th number. The optimality is assured by calculating the min and max of the results on every subarray then apply the recurrence relation. The time complexity is O(n^3) since there are O(n^2) subproblems and each takes O(n).

Edit:

Explanation:

For dynamic programming, it's crucial to identify what is the subproblem and how a subproblem relates to other subproblems. For this problem with say `n` numbers (hence `n - 1` operators), the subproblem is: what is the min/max value you can get by combining the numbers and operators in between the `i`-th number and the `j`-th number (inclusive).

The base case is `i = j`, we have only one number, the min/max is itself.

For any `j > i`, the subproblems to this problem is for k ranging from `i` to `j - 1` the minimum and maximum value of the left part (subproblem with `i` and `k` as the two endpoints) and the right part (subproblem with `k + 1` and `j` as the two endpoints). For each `k` what we are essentially doing is applying the `k`-th operator as the last operator, hence the minimum we can get for each `k` is the minimum of left (`operator`) minimum of right (similarly for maximum). (Note that the operators are either `*` or `+`, which are monotonic so we combine minimums to get minimum and maximums to get maximum. For a more generic problem with more operators such as `-` or `/` we probably need to consider a lot of cases but the basic structure should be the same). So the recurrence relations is simply

`minimum(i, j) = min(minimum(i, k) [operator] minimum(k + 1, j) for each k)`

`(same for max)`

We have to solve each subproblem (total `O(n^2)` of them) for once only and cache it (or memoize it as people would say) and each subproblem requires an `O(n)` loop to solve. Hence the time complexity is `O(n^3)`.

A deeper understanding of dynamic programming would really help you solve all similar problems. I suggest read something about it if you are not sure what to expect in such a setting.

Comment: It would help OP if you can explain your implementation.

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm in detail?

Comment: I think there are `n` subproblems more precisely as many as number of operators and each one would take `O(n^2)`, because once you divide a string into two parts, each one would end up in a list and you need to consider every combination of the values in that list. Total complexity is `O(n^3)` again.

Comment: That's an alternative way to solve it. Both are valid.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be categorized as divide and conquer problem with memoization.

Imagine your string is `s = s1 op1 s2 op2 s3 op3 s4`

Now you can partition `s` at each `op`

Lets say you partition `s` at `op1` to give you two strings :

Left string :  `s1` and

Right string : `s2 op2 s3 op3 s4`.

Lets say the minimum, maximum value that can be obtained for left string are `min1, max1`

and for right string are : `min2, max2`.

You might think that `min1 op1 min2` is minimum and `max1 op1 max2` is maximum

But not yet done.

You need to do it for each `op` and accumulate values for `min` and `max`. Why? Because the partition at `op1` might not be optimal.

Then out of all those partitions, pick the `min(mins)` and `max(maxs)`

You could recursively implement this with remembering the results in Java like:

```
private static int[] recurse( String input, Map<String, int[]> map ) {
    if ( map.containsKey(input) ) {
        return map.get(input);
    }

    int[] ans = null;
    List<Integer> mins = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> maxs = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {
        if ( !Character.isDigit( input.charAt(i) ) ) {
            String left = input.substring(0, i);
            String right = input.substring(i+1);

            int[] leftResult = recurse(left, map);
            int[] rightResult = recurse(right, map);

            int leftMin = leftResult[0];
            int leftMax = leftResult[1];

            int rightMin = rightResult[0];
            int rightMax = rightResult[1];

            switch( input.charAt(i) ) 
            {
            case '+':
                mins.add( leftMin + rightMin );
                maxs.add( leftMax + rightMax );
                break;
            case '*':
                mins.add( leftMin*rightMin );
                maxs.add( leftMax*rightMax );
                break;
            default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( mins.isEmpty() || maxs.isEmpty() ) {
        ans = new int[]{Integer.valueOf(input), Integer.valueOf(input)};
    } else {
        ans[0] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        ans[1] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for ( int i = 0; i < mins.size(); i++ ) {
            ans[0] = Math.min( ans[0], mins.get(i) );
            ans[1] = Math.max( ans[1], maxs.get(i) );
        }
    }

    map.put( input, ans );
    return ans;
}

private static void getMinMax( String in ) {
    if ( in.isEmpty() ) {
        System.out.println("0 0");
        return;
    }
    int[] ans = recurse(in, new HashMap<String, int[]>() );
    System.out.println(ans[1] + " " + ans[0]);

}
```